# How do I verify okhttp is using http/2 for a request?

Tags: okhttp, http2

How can I verify that okhttp negotiated http/2 successfully and did not use https/1.1 instead? Is there some info in the response I can check?

Thanks,
-Tony

Answer (score 5):

FYI since okhttp 3.0 or so `OkHttp-Selected-Protocol` is not printed.

The protocol can be easily seen in the response object though.

[image: Protocol in response]

Comment: Thanks, was quite helpful. Another option can be adding a custom network interceptor and log `response.protocol()` in it. https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I got the answer. If I print out the response headers I got this:
OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: h2

Am I to assume it negotiated successfully the response for http/2?

Thanks!
-tony

Comment: It's not printing such header in newer versions. You need to take the app in debug mode and track the response ->protocol -> name

Answer (score 1):

You can check protocol by calling:

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();  // first get response from server
Protocol protocol = response.protocol();                // check which protocol was used
```