# How to use http/2 with Okhttp on Android devices?

Tags: android, http, okhttp, http2

I'M testing a site that supports HTTP/2,[like this](https://www.h2check.org/#google.it),
and I try to use okhttp to send the request:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://www.google.it")
        .build();


okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
        Log.d("TestHttp", "OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: " + response.header("OkHttp-Selected-Protocol"));
        Log.d("TestHttp", "Response code is " + response.code());
    }
});
```

In the log I got something like this:

```
OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
```

The okhttpClient chose to use http/1.1, how can I  force it to use HTTP/2?

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1455#issuecomment-75818950),It seams that the okhttp support h2-16 and higher.

Comment: which okHttp are you using? based on this https://publicobject.com/2015/03/17/okhttp-2-3-has-http2/ version 2.3 have the http/2

Comment: @Yazan I use version 2.4.0

Comment: Are you running this on an Android device, or on your desktop? On desktop JVMs you need Jetty-ALPN. You can see details here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Building

Comment: @JesseWilson I run this on Android device.

Comment: Just my grain of salt: here is [another website](https://www.httptwo.com/htt2-and-google-analytics/) that supports HTTP/2 and that you can use for testing, look for the API part. There is some dissonance caused by servers and clients supporting different drafts. Furthermore, some servers opt to choose protocol based on the ordering of the ALPN list presented by the client while others will use their own internal preferences, the [rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7301#section-3.1) is AFAIU OK with both.

Comment: Which Android release? ALPN wants Android 5 or newer.

Comment: @JesseWilsion I use Android 4.4.4. When I test on Android 5.0.0,I got the expect result,OkHttp use http/2 protocol. Is that means I can only use Okhttp on Android 5 or newer to send http/2 request?(sorry for my pool english...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okhttp 2.5+ only support http/2 above 5.0+ via ALPN.

but you can modify the source code to support http/2 above 4.0+ via NPN.

Comment: how to config ALPN？

Comment: So OkHttp 3.9.0+ handles HTTP2 out of the box, using ALPN provided by Google Play Services.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to initialize your OkHttpClient in proper way.

Kotlin:

```
val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_2, Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
    .build()

// Your client will now try to use HTTP 2 if possible. If not, then HTTP 1.1 will be used.
```

Java:

```
List<Protocol> protocols = new ArrayList<Protocol>();
protocols.add(Protocol.HTTP_2);
protocols.add(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .protocols(protocols)
        .build();

// Your client will now try to use HTTP 2 if possible. If not, then HTTP 1.1 will be used.
```

If you wish to check if HTTP 2 is being used, see my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72983159/1735603